# Two similar dynamic drop down list selection selenium web driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have two dynamic drop down list which are similar, I'm unable to select from the second drop down list. Below is the html:

```
<div id="list" class="x-list">
<div id="list-list" class="x-list-list-ct">
<ul>
<li class="x-item" role="option">US Dollar - USD</li> 
<li class="x-item x-list-selected x-list-item-over" role="option">Afghan Afghani - AFN</li> //<--this is my 1st selection from 1st dropdown list
<li class="x-item" role="option">Albanian Lek - ALL</li>
<li class="x-item" role="option">Algerian Dinar - DZD</li>
<li class="x-item" role="option">Angolan Kwanza - AOA</li>
<li class="x-item" role="option">Argentine Peso - ARS</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

<div id="list" class="x-list">
<div id="list-list" class="x-list-list-ct">
<ul>
<li class="x-item x-list-selected x-list-item-over" role="option">US Dollar - USD</li> //<--this is my default hover selection
<li class="x-item" role="option">Afghan Afghani - AFN</li> 
<li class="x-item" role="option">Albanian Lek - ALL</li>
<li class="x-item" role="option">Algerian Dinar - DZD</li>
<li class="x-item" role="option">Angolan Kwanza - AOA</li>
<li class="x-item" role="option">Argentine Peso - ARS</li>
</ul>
</div>
</d
```

When a element is selected or hovered the class name changes to 'x-item x-list-selected x-list-item-over'

For the first list I use 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[text()[contains(.,'Afghan Afghani - AFN')]]")).click();

When I do the same for second list, the element gets selected but the list doesn't close.

Comment: Have you tried to debug without the 2nd dropdown selection? It could be possible that the list also doesn't close for the 1st dropdown until you perform an action to another element (in this case the 2nd dropdown). Please try either of the following: 1.) try to select an option for the first dropdown without selecting for the 2nd and see whether the list closes. 2.) try to change the order of selection e.g. perform actions on the 2nd dropdown before interacting with the 1st dropdown. item 2 works, then it's possible that you just need to focus / interact with another element after.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

For selecting from first list

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[1]/div/ul/li[text()='Afghan Afghani - AFN']")).click();
```

For selecting from second list

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[2]/div/ul/li[text()='Afghan Afghani - AFN']")).click();
```

Comment: The div elements are dynamic, so I can't rely on them

Answer (score 0):

Try these xpath, use 1 for the first div, 2 for the second div

```
"//div[@id='list'][1]//li[text()='Afghan Afghani - AFN']"
```

or 
`"//li[text()='Afghan Afghani - AFN'][1]"`
and  `"//li[text()='Afghan Afghani - AFN'][2]"`

I think the list will automatically close when you interact with other elements on the page, so example, try sending an blank space to another element (like a button) so the list loses focus and will close by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like this code

```
 (//div[@id='list'])[1]
```